# How to make second drop down list visible once first ddl is selected?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making a comment / request form for my website and in order to allow my users to 
be as specific as possible I have a drop down list listing all of the 8 categories on my website.  Once the first category of the drop down list is selected I am trying to make the ddl that corresponds with the selected category visible.  How do I keep the second ddls invisible until the proper category is selected?

Here is the html code i have so far:

```
    Select a Category:

    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMaintab" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
    onselectedindexchanged="ddlMaintab_SelectedIndexChanged">

    <asp:ListItem Text="- Select - " Value=""></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="U" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Re" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Merc" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Rep" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="A" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Refi" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Rete" Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>


    <br /><br />

    Sub Category:
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSub" runat="server" Visible="false" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="app" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="CS" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Saved" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="JLB" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Completed" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Search" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Pre-approved" Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Notes" Value="8"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Document" Value="9"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Deal" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" Visible="false" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="app" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="CS" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" Visible="false" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="app" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="CS" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl3" runat="server" Visible="false" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="app" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="CS" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl4" runat="server" Visible="false" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="app" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="CS" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl5" runat="server" Visible="false" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="app" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="CS" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl6" runat="server" Visible="false" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="app" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="CS" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Thank you so much btw this site is awesome

Comment: Instead of having this many dropdownlists, why not have one that will be populated dynamically based on the selections.

Comment: Post this part of the backend code ddlMaintab_SelectedIndexChanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement cascading drop down lists. See here (caveat: own blog posting) for more details on how to do this:

[Code Snippet: Cascading DropDownLists](http://codersbarn.com/post/2007/07/21/Code-Snippet-Cascading-DropDownLists.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish this.
First, you could have all of the subsequent controls set to visible=invisible and have an event that fires onchange... Or you could just have one drop down and create a new one "onchange".

You could also use ajax to only partially post back and render new drop downs as needed.